# Jumping effect in games

Tags: xna

I'm currently trying to make a basic platformer with XNA and I'm wondering how to create a "jumping effect."  I currently have basic keyboard input which allows for sideways movement, but I would like my sprite to slowly progress into a jump rather than instantly teleporting there (right now I have something like Rectangle.Y += 40 every time I jump, making the sprite instantly appear there).  Does anyone have any insight?

Comment: You could add a second vector for motion (in addition to position). Then, on every update, add the motion vector to the position vector. On a jump, set the motion vector to move the player up slowly. At the peak of the jump, change it to move the player down. After the jump, set to zero. Need to be careful if several things can affect the motion vector though (add to it instead of set it so you don't overwrite existing motion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally across how to implement this in XNA/C#, but in Flash games I've made I just added a vertical velocity property. I'll try write everything as C# as I can..

Example; create the velocity property:

```
float verticalVelocity = 0;
```

Vertical velocity should be constantly reduced (by gravity). Set up a gravity property somewhere accessible from your player:

```
float Gravity = 2.5;
```

And in your `update()` method for the player, increment the `verticalVelocity` by `Gravity`. Also increment the `Y` position of your player by the `verticalVelocity`. This will simulate falling:

```
verticalVelocity += Gravity;
Position.Y += verticalVelocity; // this may be -= in XNA, not sure where the y axis beings
```

When you hit a surface, the velocity should be reset to 0.

And finally, to jump, simply subtract a given value from `verticalVelocity`:

```
public void Jump(float height)
{
    // Only jump if standing on a surface.
    if(verticalVelocity == 0)
        verticalVelocity -= height;
}
```

Comment: For extensibility, you should create a `PhysicsSimulation` (or similar) class and have it contain a `List<Body>` where Body is a base class that the player, and any other object that should be affected, all inherit from. Then you can just update the `PhysicsSimulation` and it can take care of the gravity for all objects. This allows you to make the gameplay much richer, without too much difficulty.

Comment: @annonymously That's a suggestion for the OP and not myself ya?

Answer (score 0):

You'll eventually want to add gravity and possibly other forces to your game, so I highly recommend you save yourself a lot of pain and implement some kind of basic force system. This can be done using `Vector2`s, as you can just add them to the speed of your character. Then just apply an instantaneous force to your character to push it up.

If you really don't want to use a physics engine, you can make a `Vector2` with the high point of the jump for the `Y` and the characters `X`, and then use the [`Vector2.Lerp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector2.lerp.aspx) method to interpolate between the characters position and the end point of the jump.

This is generally a very bad system to use, and I highly recommend you either use an existing physics engine, or make your own simple one.

Answer (score 0):

use a [sinusoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine_wave)
code should look something like this:

```
float ground = 0.0f;
float angle  = 330.0f;

jump(){
if(ground == 0.0f)ground = Rectangle.Y;
  if(Rectangle.Y <= ground)
  {
    Rectangle.Y+=Math.Sin(angle/(Math.Pi*180));
    angle++;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you place this code in the Update method it won't work. Your logic is a bit off, the character will just move upwards at a variable rate. I think what you actually want to do is: `Rectangle.Y = (int)(ground+Math.Sin(angle/(Math.PI*180)));`

Comment: thats why I use `+=` instead of `=`

Comment: Using `+=` will add the right operand to the left one, whereas here we want to add the *`ground`* to the `Sin` value and then assign it to the `Rectangle`.

Comment: no we don't, ground is only used to hold the current ground value, that way we can calculate when the player has finished jumping and reached the ground again. granted this won't on irregular surfaces, but this is meant as a simple example.

Answer (score 0):

You can accurately create a gravity effect if you modify the ySpeed dynamically, as opposed to just adding 40.

You want to declare a ySpeed

```
ySpeed = 0;
```

Then you want to use an acceleration variable

```
acceleration = 0.25;
```

Okay, now that we've done that, let's add gravity, provided that our player isn't touching the floor.

```
if(playerLocationY + playerHeight > floorLocationY)
{
     gravity = false;
}
else
{
    gravity = true;
}

if(gravity)
{
    ySpeed += acceleration;
}
```

Now that we've got that down, we want to include something that allows us to jump.

```
if(KeyPressed == UP)
{
    ySpeed -= acceleration;
}
```

This will move our player in the upward direction

We now want to make sure we actually move, so let's add one last line and we're done.

```
playerLocationY += ySpeed;
```

Congratulations, you made it.